# Subroutines in MIPS and other beginner silliness

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine

I'm using Project Euler to learn MIPS, specifically using Problem 6 to learn how to use a subroutine. Unfortunately, I am doing something very wrong because my answer that I'm getting is far too large in magnitude. Is my problem here with how I am using the subroutine, or is it something else entirely?

```
## p6.asm
##
## Andrew Levenson, 2010
## Project Euler, Problem 6
##
## Calculate the difference
## between the sum of the squares
## and the square of the sum
## of all natural numbers n
## such that n < 1000
        .text
        .globl  main

main:
init:   
    ## Registers
        ori     $t0, $0, 0x0        # $t0 will be used for scratch
        ori     $t1, $0, 0x0        # $t1 is the loop counter and n
        ori     $t2, $0, 0x0        # $t2 will be the sum of the squares
        ori     $t3, $0, 0x0        # $t3 will be the square of the sum
        ori     $t4, $0, 0x3E8      # $t4 = 1000, the limit

loop:
    ## Main loop
        addiu   $t1, $t1, 0x1       # Increment n

        sltu    $t0, $t1, $t4       # Is n less than 1000?
        beq     $t0, $0, diff       # if $t0 == 0 then jump to diff
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op

        addu    $t3, $t3, $t1       # sum = sum + n

        move    $a0, $t1            # put n in $a0
        jal     square              # jump to square and save position to $ra
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op

        addu    $t2, $t2, $a0       # The sum of the squares =
                                    # sum + n **2

        j       loop                # jump to loop
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op




square:
    ## Subroutine that squares a given number
        mul     $a0, $a0, $a0       # Argument = Argument ** 2
        jr      $ra                 # jump to $ra
                                    # $ra = instruction where jal was called
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op


diff:
    ## Finds the difference of $t2 and $t3
    ## But first, we have to square $t3
        move    $a0, $t3            # puts $t3 in $a0
        jal     square              # jump to square and save position to $ra
        sll     $0, $0, $0          # no op

        move    $t3, $a0            # $t3 = $a0 = $t3 ** 2

        subu    $t0, $t2, $t3       # $t0 = $t2 - $t3


print:
        li      $v0, 0x1            # system call #1 - print int
        move    $a0, $t0
        syscall                     # execute

        li      $v0, 0xA            # system call #10 - exit
        syscall

## End of Program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that [question 6](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=6) asks you to work with the numbers from 1 to 100, whereas your code works with 1 to 999!

The subroutine call looks OK.  Some suggestions:

1) You have a strange mixture of basic ops vs. pseudo-ops.  The `ori` instructions at the top can be written using `li` (just as the constants for the syscalls at the bottom are).  Alternatively, if you deliberately want to use basic ops as a learning exercise, note that `move $a0, $t1` can be written as `addu $a0, $t1, $0` (or `or $a0, $1, $0` also works).

2) The conditional branch with `sltu` and `beq` can be written as `bge $t1, $t4, diff`.  This is a pseudo-op which expands to `sltu` and `beq`, but is interesting because it automatically uses `$1` as a temporary register - by convention this register is reserved for use as the "assembler temporary" and named `$at`.

3) `sll $0, $0, $0` is really a `sllv` instruction, as the shift amount there is a register.  The canonical MIPS no-op is `sll $0, $0, 0` which assembles to an opcode of `0x00000000`.  Better still, just write `nop`.

4) Where explicit branch delay slots are being used (note that some assemblers will reorder instructions automatically to fill them - e.g. `gas` does this unless you tell it not to with `.set reorder`), it's helpful to clearly mark them in some way so that they stand out.  A useful convention is to give them an extra bit of indentation:

```
move    $a0, $t1            # put n in $a0
jal     square              # jump to square and save position to $ra
 nop                        # no-op
```

(A `nop` tends to stand out anyway, but if you start trying to fill them with useful instructions, you will quickly go mad if you don't mark them in *some* way.)

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response! Unfortunately, the program still yields an incorrect answer. Do you see anything I could be doing wrong algorithmically?

Comment: Nevermind, I actually just figured it out! I was using the numbers 1..99, instead of 1..100. Changing `$t4` to `0x65` fixed it. Thank you again!